# Firefox launches Anaconda Navigator

Tags: 18.04, firefox, launcher, anaconda

I'm running Firefox 75.0 and Anaconda3-2020.02 on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

I've just installed Anaconda Navigator and created a launcher for it by following the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017284/cant-create-anaconda-shortcut-to-launch-from-desktop-on-ubuntu-17-10).

However, since then, when I launch Firefox, I get Firefox but the Dash, top-panel, app switcher (Alt+Tab) all show the 'Firefox' session as being Anaconda Navigator. Running `firefox` from a terminal has the same effect.

I guess that in creating the Anaconda launcher I have inadvertently overwritten some Firefox config. How can I resolve this?

navigator.sh:

```
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/carl/anaconda3/bin/python
export PATH=/home/carl/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
python /home/carl/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator
```

navigator.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Anaconda-Navigator
GenericName=Anaconda
Exec=/bin/bash "/home/carl/anaconda3/navigator.sh"
Icon=/home/carl/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/anaconda-icon-256x256.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

Clicking the Anaconda Navigator launcher does launch Anaconda Navigator correctly, as does `/bin/bash "/home/carl/anaconda3/navigator.sh"` from the terminal.

Comment: @K7AAY Done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has a module called [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator), which presumably was invoking my `navigator.desktop` file.

I renamed it to `anaconda-navigator.desktop` and rebooted, and everything now works properly.